# Merge array in for loop using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following query in loop for select records

```
$shopchairs=$rows['shop_chairs'];  //coming dynamically  i.e. 1 or 3 or 4 
$result = [];
for($i=1;$i<=$shopchairs;$i++)
{
    $query = //SELECT QUERY WITH WHERE CONDITION;
    $res = $query->result_array();
    $result[] = [
    'chairnumber' => $i,
    'status' => $querys->num_rows() > 0 ? 'booked' : 'available',
    'estimateTime' => "",
    ];

}
echo "<pre>";print_R($result);
```

Now I just want to merge "estimateTime" which is coming from $res(array) with $result(array), How can I do this?
Right now my $res showing following array in the loop

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shopId] => 2
            [duration] => 20
            [estimatedTime] => 11.3000
        )
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

I just want to merge estimatedTime with $result array

Comment: You should do a `while` loop on `$res`. And calculate then put in `$result`array.

Comment: @Sougata Bose: can you please write code so i can check in my side

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal You can update your question with sample input and your expected output.